# How to use `let` and `where` together?

Tags: haskell

I have the following code

```
initModel :: [Double] -> Model
initModel xs = do
 let weights = [f x | x <- xs]
     biases = [g x | x <- xs]
```

and I would like to define `f` and `g` by adding a `where` clause at the end of the `initModel` function. But, when I added like this

```
initModel :: [Double] -> Model
initModel xs = do
 let weights = [f x | x <- xs]
     biases = [g x | x <- xs]
  where
   f x = x
   g x = x
 Model weights biases
```

The last line gives `Parse error on input 'Model'` error. I have tried many combinations of indentations for the `where` clause but none has worked so far.

Comment: FWIW: in my personal code style, I never use `do` and `where`, preferring to use only `let` with `do`. Mixing all together looks cumbersome to me: if I read `performFoo x y (f z)` in the middle of a long `do` block and wonder what `f` is, I need to look up for `let`s, and down for `where`s. Using only `let` (IMO) makes the code easier to read, since I only have to look up.

Comment: @chi Surely there are exceptions to this? A `where` can span multiple pattern guards, which a `let` can't do.

Comment: @amalloy To be honest, in such scenario I wish I could write `f pat1 pat2 let x = def | guard1 x = code1 | guard2 x = code2`, but this is not valid syntax, and `where` is the only simple choice. Still, having both that guards/`where` scenario _and_ `do` blocks in the `codeN` parts is a rather uncommon case -- I'd say that never happened to me (in my limited experience).

Comment: I would use `let` in `do` if I think the reader needs to read that definition to make sense of the block, `where` when the definition is not necessary to grok the overall flow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following shows some possible choices:

```
initModel xs = do
  let weights = [f x | x <- xs]
        where f x = x
      biases = [g x | x <- xs]
        where
          g x = x
  Model weights biases

initModel xs = do
  let weights = [f x | x <- xs]
      biases = [g x | x <- xs]
  Model weights biases
  where
  f x = x
  g x = x
```

In general: `where` must be attached to a binding (an equality or a clause in a `case`), and therefore indented more than that binding; and any bindings inside the `where` must be indented at least as much as any enclosing block (more than the enclosing block if you want to continue the enclosing block later).

Comment: "[...]and therefore indented more than that binding;": In the first case, where is `where` binding then and how did you decide how much to indent?

Comment: @onurcanbektas The first `where` attaches to the definition of `weights`, and therefore must be indented at least one character more than `weights` is.

Comment: @amalloy oh, now I see. Thanks a lot.